# PHP To AutoFill Select with 1 - 25

Tags: php, html

I am trying to fill my `Select` with options 1 - 25 but it remains empty.  This is the syntax I have tried but when you click on the arrow for the select it is an empty drop down.  What must be altered in order to have the numbers 1 - 25 populate in this box?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server"><title>Test</title></head>
<body>
<form id="OrderingForm" runat="server">
    <div id="OrderInfo" runat="server">
        <table id="orderinginfo">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <select>
                    <?php
                        for ($i=1; $i<=25; $i++)
                        {
                            ?>
                                <option value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>
                            <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Don't see anything wrong with this code. Is php installed correctly?

Comment: File is `.php` extension?

Comment: Works for me. Sounds like an environment issue.

Comment: @DavidWyly - trying to execute through notepad++ on Win10 64bit machine

Comment: How would you _execute_ it through notepad++?  You need a webserver with PHP installed.

Comment: Does `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` not show your PHP info? If not shows, PHP is misconfigured, not installed, and/or is not running correctly.

Comment: @DavidWyly - phpinfo() returns my php info

Comment: Well that's odd. Do you have error reporting turned on? Can you do a PHP echo anywhere else in the code to ensure that PHP is echoing properly?

Comment: I do not have error reporting turned on.  Let me google enabling that and see what is returned.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have an environment issue -- I say that because the code works perfectly for me.

Since you are running windows, XAMPP will probably be a good choice to get a local webserver humming using XAMPP. [This tutorial may help you get started](https://blog.udemy.com/xampp-tutorial/).

Once you get XAMPP installed and configured correctly, you can test if PHP is running properly by creating a test `.php` file and putting the following code into it:

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

If you see a rendered page with all your PHP information, you should be good to go.

After that, if you're still having problems, ensure you have error reporting turned on:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```